# I want to close an image, my close button is not working, I don't want the entire page to close just the image

Tags: javascript, html, css

*Trying to close an image, but my close button is not working.

Added a button to an image, but my button does not work when I call 
 the code*

Trying to close image with this code:

```
document.getElementById("closeButton").addEventListener("click", closeB, false);
function closeB(){
    this.parentNode.style.display = 'none';}
```

Unable to close image with this code

Answer (score 0):

Maybe should be `parentElement`

```
document.getElementById("closeButton").addEventListener("click", closeB, false);
function closeB(){
  this.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but parentElement did not work.

Comment: `parentElementNode` ?

Answer (score 0):

put a id on your `img` tag called `image`. just like this

```
<img id="image" src="https://a.optmstr.com/app/src/Themes/Lightbox/Metro/assets/images/metro-icon.png">
    <button id="closeButton">button</button>
```

below the js code

```
document.getElementById("closeButton").addEventListener("click", closeB, false);
function closeB(){
    document.getElementById('image').style.display = 'none'; 
}
```